# Android BLE command sending is not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am struggling through one strange issue that is Command send from android device to BLE dongle. Here i have two buttons **Button1** and **Button2**. On click of each button i am trying to send to different command to BLE dongle. Elaboration of issue is below:

1. Fragment launch with two buttons **Button1** and **Button2**
2. Click on **Button1**
3. Command send to BLE dongle sucessfully
4. Then clicked in **Button2** command doesn't send to BLE.
5. Again re-run and  Fragment launch now i clicked **Buttons2**
6. Command send successfully
7. Them clicked on **Button1** command doesn't send.

*

> Concussion- Command send only on first click of first button.

*
Now here is code which i have used
Below is code i am calling at from onCreateView() of Fragment to initialize the services and Broadcast receiver.

```
 if(SingleTon.getInstance().getDeviceAddress() !=null && SingleTon.getInstance().getDeviceName() != null) {
    if(!SingleTon.getInstance().isLEServiceGattInit())
    settingObj.deviceControl(getActivity(), SingleTon.getInstance().getDeviceAddress(), SingleTon.getInstance().getDeviceName());
}
```

Now methods which will get call form above code-

```
public  void deviceControl(Context context,String deviceAddress, String devicename ){
progressServices = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressServices = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
        "Looking for Services....", true);

this.mcontext = context;
this.mDeviceAddress = deviceAddress;
this.mDeviceName = devicename;
initServices();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(progressServices.isShowing()) {
            progressServices.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(mcontext,"Issue in BLE, not able to advertise Services/UUIDs.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}, 6000);
}
    private void initServices(){
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(mcontext, BluetoothLeService.class);
    mcontext.bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, getActivity().BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mcontext.registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
}



  private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
            mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();

            if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize");
            }
            // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
            mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBluetoothLeService = null;
        }
    };

        private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = true;

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                SingleTon.getInstance().setLEServiceGattInit(false);

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
                SingleTon.getInstance().setmBluetoothLeService(mBluetoothLeService);

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            }
        }
    };



   private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
        if (gattServices == null) return;
        String uuid;
        String unknownServiceString = "Unknown Services";
        String unknownCharaString = "Unknown Characteristic";
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData
                = new ArrayList<>();
        mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<>();

        // Loops through available GATT Services.
        String LIST_NAME = "NAME";
        String LIST_UUID = "UUID";
        for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {

            uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
            if(uuid.contains("ff02")){

                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattService.getCharacteristics();
                // Loops through available Characteristics.
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
                    if (gattCharacteristic.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString("0000c002-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))) {

                        SingleTon.getInstance().setListWriteCharecteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                        progressServices.dismiss();
                        SingleTon.getInstance().setLEServiceGattInit(true);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
        private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        return intentFilter;
    }
```

Now below is code which we are calling for command send on each button click.

```
btn_head_up.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            sendHexCommand(CommandListHex.Hex20BIT_ACT_HEAD_UP);
        return  true;
    }
});

private void sendHexCommand(String cmd){
if(SingleTon.getInstance().getDeviceAddress() !=null && SingleTon.getInstance().getDeviceName() != null) {
        settingObj.sendCommand(cmd, SingleTon.getInstance().getListWriteCharecteristic(), SingleTon.getInstance().getmBluetoothLeService());
} else{
    showDialog(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.dialogtitle), "First do configuration for Bluetooth");
}
}
```

And now finally code to send command

```
public void sendCommand(String Control_INST, ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charFromSinglonton ,
                            BluetoothLeService bleGATTService){
        for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattChar :charFromSinglonton) {
            if (charFromSinglonton != null) {
                final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gattChar;

                boolean status = bleGATTService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic, hexStringToByteArray(Control_INST));

                if (status) {
                    SingleTon.getInstance().setCorrectWriteGattCharecteristic(gattChar);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Thanks for dumping the unedited source code here and what is your actual problem?

Comment: Command is not going on second click. From android device command is sending only on click of first button.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber If you able to  get rid this issue it will be great help for me.

Comment: Any one have any clue how to get rid this issue?

Comment: I think the problem is in Singleton !

Comment: @BOUTERBIATOualid it would be great help if you able to elaborate it more.

Comment: Try calling this method without any conditions on both the button click.. Button one and Button Two..  settingObj.deviceControl(getActivity(), SingleTon.getInstance().getDeviceAddress(), SingleTon.getInstance().getDeviceName());

Comment: @Stallion. Thanks a lot for your attention. Already tried this, problem with this approach is- "Gatt Server already connected and gain we are trying to connect with Gatt." If you want i can post my "Service" code too.

Comment: I can suggest an approach here that can be changed. Once your Fragment is Visible, create connection in background and then enable both the button's. So that both the buttons can use same instances for sending command. Now once the fragment is removed from view you can de-referrer the last created connection. I mean call initServices() once in fragment and let both the action on buttons use same instance

Comment: @Stallion. Yes i am doing in same way.  1. After Fragment get created the we are calling initService(); that means Gatt server initialized.  2. After that we have two Button in same Fragments, and we trying to send commands from the same Fragment. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: for the failure case what are you seeing for status value in' onCharacteristicWrite()

Comment: If you click the same button twice(like first button) what will happen? Send command twice or only one time ?

Comment: @RustFisher You gave one small clue and i solved my problem. I want to give your comment as accepted answer. Please post your comment as answer. Thanks for your clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you click the same button twice(like first button) what will happen? Send command twice or only one time ?